# Booktabs table does not show in pdf or doc

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, tex, tinytex

I get an error when trying to create a pdf that has a `booktabs` table in it. If I delete the table code, the pdf is created without a problem.

`RStudio`: Latest version

`R`: latest version

`tinytex`: latest version

Below is my `Rmd` file:

```
---
title: "table"
author: "Author"
date: "2/13/2021"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
includes:
  in_header: preamble.tex
---

Something here

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Descriptive Statistics}
    \label{tab:descriptiveStatistics}
    {
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
            \toprule
             & Weight  \\
            \cmidrule[0.4pt]{1-2}
            Valid & 13  \\
            Missing & 0  \\
            Mean & 170.769  \\
            Std. Deviation & 29.255  \\
            Minimum & 140.000  \\
            Maximum & 235.000  \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    }
\end{table}
```

Below is my `preamble.tex` file:

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
```

The error that I get is as follows:

```
output file: test.knit.md

! Undefined control sequence.
l.81             \toprule

Error: LaTeX failed to compile test.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See test.log for more info.
In addition: Warning message:
In has_crop_tools() : 
Tool(s) not installed or not in PATH: pdfcrop, ghostcript
-> As a result, figure cropping will be disabled.
Execution halted
```

Comment: Another solution for tables in LaTeX would be: https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, I am writing a book on how to teach stats with [JASP](http://jasp-stats.org). JASP allows one to copy tables as LaTex (need booktabs package), which has the format shown above. Thus, it is less time consuming for me to use the format above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `preamble.tex` isn't included because your yaml header is wrong. Should be:

```
---
title: "table"
author: "Author"
date: "2/13/2021"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---
```

Then it works.

I would also recommend using `kableExtra`. It basically produces LaTeX code and saves you a lot of time making tables in my experience. You can set `keep_tex: yes` (also under `pdf_document:`) to double-check what is being produced.

Comment: Thank you so much. I noticed that it works for pdf files but not for doc or html. Do I need to add anything in the yaml header for it to work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's my biggest issue with R Markdown: Tables are not converted to all formats. `knitr::kable` and `kableExtra` work well for PDF and HTML. But if you want to have nice tables in doc and docx you need `flextable` or something similar.

Comment: Personally I wrote a function to get my tables right. I use `knitr:::pandoc_to() == "latex"` to check if something is knitted to PDF and `knitr:::pandoc_to() == "docx"` for word.